# combobox items not displaying

Tags: asp.net, ajax, combobox

This question has been asked here before, but the author wasn't very clear and got no answers (1st ref). Why aren't my combobox items displaying correctly? It is almost like they are there, but not connected to the combobox (notice my label, it shows up halfway down the page instead of right underneath the combobox when I run it). I get no errors on the page, which is good (different than when I tried doing this in VS2005), and the combobox displays fine, but when I click it, nothing is there.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
            DropDownStyle="DropDownList">
          <asp:ListItem>thisis</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>mynetwork</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>getoffmyjunk</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>itsmine</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>illkillyou</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>forrealz</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>what</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>didyousaysomething</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>didn'tthinkso</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>meh</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ComboBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server">default text</asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322922/combo-box-items-does-not-display-below-of-combo-box-why

I'm having the same problem as this guy:
http://p2p.wrox.com/book-asp-net-ajax-programmers-reference-asp-net-2-0-asp-net-3-5-isbn-978-0-470-10998-4/80267-ajax-combobox-not-displaying-item-list-correctly.html

Comment: You should have added an image of your issue to visualize your problems. On my system it looks ok. But normally you need an ToolkitScriptmanager instead of an Scriptmanager, i would get an exception from the toolkit, strange. Also i would suggest to use different TagPrefixes for your AjaxControlToolkit dll than for ASP.Net.

Comment: There's really nothing to see lol..other than what I described: an empty combobox and a label "lbl" halfway down the screen, as if the page statically allocated space for the listitems underneath the combobox (the more listitems I put, the farther the lbl goes down the screen), instead of placing them inside the cobmobox.

Comment: Sounds like you either have a) a javascript error on the page, or b) some conflict with your css styles. Have you tried using Firebug in Firefox to inspect the elements and see what's going on?

Comment: Actually using the ToolkilScriptManager just worked for me. I'm sure I tested it when I asked this, and it didn't work, but it did now. If you want to put it as an answer, I'll mark you up lol. Ill just +1 the comment for now, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use toolkitscriptmanager xD
wanted to give the answer to Tim, but he won't put his comment as an answer ;;

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks to be incorrect for the ComboBox control. You want to use the Text and Value parameters in order to get the options to display. You'll want it to look like this:

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DropDownStyle="DropDownList">
   <asp:ListItem Text="thisis" Value="thisis"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="mynetwork" Value="mynetwork"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="getoffmyjunk" Value="getoffmyjunk"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ComboBox>
```

Note: You may also be running into issues with your control tag declaration. For example, when I import the AJAX Control Toolkit into my applications, and add the proper references, I wind up using the tag "cc1" for all of the AJAX Control Toolkit controls. You may need to double check these references as well.

Comment: Actually, when you place text between the tags, it sets the text/value property to this string for you (I tried it the way you have it just to be sure, and still nothing). Also, the tags are fine. I tried changing the tag prefix and am still getting the same result.

Comment: Interesting... I used close to the same code on my page and it worked fine. I'm looking at some of my other AJAX embedded code and for some reason I have my initial <div> tag before my <form> tag in my templates. It might be worth a shot.

Comment: Nothing. Thanks anyway though! Must be some kind of ajax scripting error..or IDFK!